# How can I Mimic Gmail's Basic HTML option

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

Does anyone know to quickly implement an alternate version of my site with just basic HTML like how GMail does it?

Comment: How is your site currently implemented? Google do that because they use JavaScript heavily in their GWT-based user interface. They just generate HTML instead of JavaScript at the server-side, and have a different URL for that version.

Comment: `>They just generate HTML instead of JavaScript` how about that!

Answer (score 3):

I know of a way...but it's not quick.

The 'Basic HTML' feature of GMail is by no means a simple offering. It's like coding an entirely different application.

You're going to have to re-code all of the client-side features as some sort of server-side functionality and re-style everything so you're not using Javascript for UI behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

You write a whole new site and display the rich (or your current one) or the HTML-only one based on user preference.